# What I have tried & about to try (Deleting Bing Webmaster Account) to fix Bing Delisted Website. Advice Appreciated

Tags: bing, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

If I delete my bing webmaster account, will it reset/delete ALL the data Bing has listed against my domain?

I ask this question because our site has been deindexed by bing - Like thousands of other people in the same boat, and I have no idea why. I've gone through bings rules, and none of them apply to us.

We suspect bing may have a caching issue whereby it continues crawling over 4000 removed pages, which we serve as a 410.- but it's worth mentioning we have not ruled out its a Cloudflare issue.

If it helps anyone else out, these are the things we have tried;
-Turned off "Crawler Hints" in Cloudflare. Initially, this helped, and to our surprise, we got re-indexed. But that was short-lived (20 days max).

- We upgraded Cloudflare from Basic to Pro, thinking we'd have more control. But it didn't help us.
- We Whitelisted bingbot IP Ranges in Cloudflare - note, CF WAS blocking some bing IPs.
- We moved server host. We did have outages.
- We moved to bigger servers and a new host.
- We removed some javascript on our pages (we used it for a graph). This didn't help.
- We used google console to help identify issues - specifically looking at page resources. We did have an issue with CSS not loading, which we fixed. But no improvement on Bing.
- We emailed Bing webmasters support - only to receive the same 'we can't be bothered templated email response'.
- Performed general housekeeping on the website and improved speed etc using pagespeed insights.

Some factors worth pointing out:
we're running NGINX & Apache. We're also using NextJs if that helps anyone.
The site is new, with no inbound links. Launched 6 months ago.

What else is left to try?

1. Our sitemaps don't include a  - though we will add this on Monday.
2. Finally, delete the bing webmaster account with the aim of starting from scratch. It's a long shot; I hope this will purge bings' cache. I'd use a new email address and signup again. Has anyone had any experience in doing this? Or does anyone know if it does clear all data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just noticed an error in my post. 
Should read;
Our sitemaps don't include a lastmod though we will add this on Monday

Comment: No, deleting your Webmaster Tools account will have no affect on how Bing indexes your website. Also, if you see an error in your question, you can edit it to correct the error rather than note the correction in a comment.